# How to turn off IIS forever?

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have just installed Sql Server and it needed IIS.

Now when I go to http://localhost/ I get

> -2147467259 (0x80004005)

I bet its IIS. How to turn it off and remove it from autostart?

Comment: What does it have to do with C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server only requires IIS if you are installing the Reporting Services functionality as well. If you don't plan on using Reporting Services, then I would remove that feature from for SQL Server installation. Then you can remove IIS.

To remove IIS, it varies depending on Operating System. It's a system component, so in Windows 7 it would be Control Panel, Programs and Features, then on the side "Turn Windows Features on or off", and uncheck IIS.

**EDIT:**

To change the port, open a Run dialog and type "inetmgr", right click "Default Web Site" under Sites, and select "Edit Bindings". Select the "http" binding, click "Edit", and change the port. Or, you can removing the binding entirely. Going one step further, you can remove the Default Web Site all together.

Comment: i don't want to remove it, just stop it from running and blocking port 80.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

**0x80004005** is a **unspecified error**, check your event log and IIS logs for more information.

---

Just disable and stop the **World Wide Web Publishing Service**:

```
sc config w3svc start= disabled
net stop w3svc
```

If you don't want it disabled, but manual instead, replace `disabled` by `demand` (don't remove space).